# subsets manipulation on vectors in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD `curRdd` of the form

```
res10: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int)], Int)] = ShuffledRDD[102]
```

with `curRdd.collect()` producing the following result.

```
Array((Vector((5,2)),1), (Vector((1,1)),2), (Vector((1,1), (5,2)),2))
```

Here **key** : vector of pairs of ints and **value**: count

Now, I want to convert it into another RDD of the same form `RDD[(scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int)], Int)]` by **percolating down the counts**.

That is `(Vector((1,1), (5,2)),2))` will contribute its count of 2 to any key which is a subset of it like `(Vector((5,2)),1)` becomes `(Vector((5,2)),3)`.

For the example above, our new RDD will have

```
(Vector((5,2)),3), (Vector((1,1)),4), (Vector((1,1), (5,2)),2)
```

How do I achieve this? Kindly help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want this instead: `((5,2),3), ((1,1),4))` ?

Comment: @Filippo all existing pairs should be preserved..only that subsets will have updated counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can introduce `subsets` operation for `Seq`:

```
implicit class SubSetsOps[T](val elems: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def subsets: Vector[Seq[T]] = elems match {
      case Seq() => Vector(elems)
      case elem +: rest => {
        val recur = rest.subsets
        recur ++ recur.map(elem +: _)
      }
    }
  }
```

`empty` subset will allways the be first element in the result vector, so you can omit it with `.tail`

Now your task is pretty obvious *`map`-`reduce`* which is *`flatMap`-`reduceByKey`* in terms of `RDD`:

```
 val result = curRdd
      .flatMap { case (keys, count) => keys.subsets.tail.map(_ -> count) }
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

#### Update

This implementation could introduce new sets in the result, if you would like to  choose only those that was presented in the original collection, you can join result with original:

```
val result = curRdd
  .flatMap { case (keys, count) => keys.subsets.tail.map(_ -> count) }
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .join(curRdd map identity[(Seq[(Int, Int)], Int)])
  .map { case (key, (v, _)) => (key, v) }
```

Note that `map identity` step is needed to convert key type from `Vector[_]` to `Seq[_]` in the original `RDD`. You can instead modify `SubSetsOps` definition substituting all occurencest of `Seq[T]` with `Vector[T]` or change definition following (hardcode `scala.collection`) way:

```
import scala.collection.SeqLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class SubSetsOps[T, F[e] <: SeqLike[e, F[e]]](val elems: F[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def subsets(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[F[T], T, F[T]]): Vector[F[T]] = elems match {
      case Seq() => Vector(elems)
      case elem +: rest => {
        val recur = rest.subsets
        recur ++ recur.map(elem +: _)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Odomotois There is an issue with the code. Given input mappings with their counts, I would like to update counts of its subset mappings where the subsets should be present in the input mappings. But the above code produces new subsets(which are not present in original input) and adds counts for them too. How do I fix this?

Comment: @CRM it's actually hard task for one partition understand what subsets can occur in another partitions. I think most obvious but probably not the most performant would be join the result `RDD` with the original `RDD` to filter-out excess sets
In general this information should be in the question update, or in the new follow-up question.

Comment: works like a charm. thanks. Regarding the performance aspect, I need to check with larger datasets to understand its effect